# Syntax reading high-volume data from the database and inserting in the array

Tags: php, mongodb

We have a few million records in the mongoDB,now i want to put them in the array
My problem is that,When I run the code, I encounter the following error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 68 bytes) in

I increase memory_limit to 2048 but not solved.

Someone has a suggestion on how to convert large data into arrays

```
$dbconn = new MongoClient();
$db = $dbconn->MyDB;
$myObj = $db->MyCollection->find();

$categoryArray=array();

$dataseries1=array();

$dataseries2=array();

foreach ($myObj as $dataset) {
  array_push($categoryArray, array($dataset["time"]));
  array_push($dataseries1, array($dataset["value"]));
  array_push($dataseries2, array($dataset["type"]));
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the data? Can you process it in chunks?

Comment: I want to show data on chart @Nigel Ren

Comment: Is the data summarised on the chart, if so can you do that on the database rather than retrieving all of the data?